# What are the main influences of the French "republican socialists" (Pierre Leroux, Louis Blanc, Jean-Jaurès)?

Tags: france, socialism, republic

What are the main influences of the French "republican socialists" (e.g. Pierre Leroux, Louis Blanc, Jean-Jaurès)?

In particular, can we trace back their ideology to Saint-Simon and Comte, and then to the Société des Idéologues (Tracy, Condorcet, Say)?

Or do they have a much larger spectrum of influences (Marx, Babeuf, etc.)?